# write to file is empty when I write from within a docker img

Tags: makefile, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

The code below is some step that is part of a MakeFile which is executed when a certain stage is run in ci/cd.

```
.PHONY:deploy_endpoint_configuration
deploy_endpoint_configuration: 
    @echo Deploying endpoint configuration
    gcloud endpoints services deploy ocr/model_adapter/predict_contracts.yaml --project $(project) &> $(project_dir)/deploy_contract.txt
    cat $(project_dir)/deploy_contract.txt | grep -Eo '\d*-\d*-\w*' | tail -n1 > $(project_dir)/config_id.txt
```

What I'm experiencing is that the content of deploy_contract.txt etc is always empty when this piece of code is executed in the pipeline (e.g. GitLab). I don't understand why? Has this to do w/ the fact that MakeFile executes a new shell for every command? Not entirely sure though, and yet this is hard to debug. I do confirm this issue when I run it as followed: gitlab-runner exec docker -here the stage- (for local debug purpose). But when I run it locally on macOS (i.e. only execute make deploy_endpoint_configuration), thus it's not wrapped in a container as before, it runs and functions like it should (read as the content of config_id and deploy_contract is not empty but contains the stdout + errorout)

for reference:
image used in the ci/cd stage = image: dsl.company.com:5000/python:3.7-buster
on top of that gcloud cli is installed to make use of gcloud commands.

Anyone an idea to why no content is written to my files? (it's for sure deploying though - so there must be something)

Comment: Can you confirm that `gcloud endpoints services deploy ocr/model_adapter/predict_contracts.yaml --project $(project)` is outputting something?

Comment: I would try running the container in interactive mode, `-it`, then running `make` manually inside the running container. You can try `make -n <target>` to see what commands make would have run.

Comment: @tankthinks indeed it's outputting relevant data. I'll try your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion is that it's because your command script relies on `bash` features.  GNU make will always run `/bin/sh` as its shell.  On some systems (like RedHat and RedHat-derived systems) `/bin/sh` is actually a link to `bash` and so makefile recipes that use `bash`-specific features will work.  I believe MacOS does the same, although I don't do Mac.

On other systems, like Debian and Debian-derived systems like Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is a simple, fast POSIX-compliant shell like `dash`, which doesn't support fancy bash things and so makefile recipes that use `bash`-specific features will not work.

Probably your container image is one of the latter type, while MacOS (your local system) uses `bash` as the shell.

You are using `&>` which is a bash-specific feature, that is not supported by POSIX shells.

You should write this using POSIX syntax, which is `>$(project_dir)/deploy_contract.txt 2>&1`

Either that or you can try overriding the shell in your makefile:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

to force make to run `bash` instead... this will work as long as the container image you're running does actually have `bash` in it.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. I was able to reshape my understanding based on your comment "You should write this using POSIX syntax, which is >$(project_dir)/deploy_contract.txt 2>&1" in addition, the following was very helpful on top of your feedback to this matter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean#:~:text=%40dbr%20cmd%202,as%20they%20occur.